# Save table in clipboad javaFx

Tags: java, javafx, tableview, clipboard

I'm starting to develop in JavaFx, I got a project and I want to know if is possible to make a "copy-paste" of a table in javaFx. I mean, I have a TableView with some data and just want to save it in the clipboard to export it to Microsoft word,or any other text editor. Is that possible?And how could I do it? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example about how you can copy/paste using a TableView. You have to extend the class according to your property types. Copy/Paste from and to e. g. Excel keeps the table structure, since it supports Ascii whitespace which is used in the code (\n, \t).

An improved solution is using mixed clipboard content in order to structure the [ClipboardContent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/input/ClipboardContent.html) also as html. Then you'll get the table structure as well in programs like Word.

TableCopyPasteCellsDemo.java

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.SelectionMode;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TableCopyPasteCellsDemo extends Application {

    private final ObservableList<Person> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList(new Person("Jacob", "Smith", 18), new Person("Isabella", "Johnson", 19), new Person("Ethan", "Williams", 20), new Person("Michael", "Brown", 21));

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {

        stage.setWidth(500);
        stage.setHeight(550);

        // create table columns
        TableColumn<Person, String> firstNameCol = new TableColumn<Person, String>("First Name");
        firstNameCol.setMinWidth(100);
        firstNameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("firstName"));


        // firstNameCol.setVisible(false); // hide column for testing view/model indices


        TableColumn<Person, String> lastNameCol = new TableColumn<Person, String>("Last Name");
        lastNameCol.setMinWidth(100);
        lastNameCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("lastName"));

        TableColumn<Person, Integer> ageCol = new TableColumn<Person, Integer>("Age");
        ageCol.setMinWidth(60);
        ageCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person, Integer>("age"));


        TableView<Person> table = new TableView<>();
        table.setPlaceholder(new Text("No content in table"));
        table.setItems(data);
        table.getColumns().addAll(firstNameCol, lastNameCol, ageCol);

        final VBox vbox = new VBox();
        vbox.setSpacing(5);
        vbox.setPadding(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));

        BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();
        borderPane.setCenter(table);

        vbox.getChildren().addAll(borderPane);

        vbox.getChildren().add( new Label( "Select cells and press CTRL+C. Paste the data into Excel or Notepad"));

        Scene scene = new Scene(vbox);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

        // enable multi-selection
        table.getSelectionModel().setCellSelectionEnabled(true);
        table.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.MULTIPLE);

        // enable copy/paste
        TableUtils.installCopyPasteHandler(table);
    }


    public static class Person {

        private final StringProperty firstName;
        private final StringProperty lastName;
        private final IntegerProperty age;

        private Person(String fName, String lName, Integer age) {
            this.firstName = new SimpleStringProperty(fName);
            this.lastName = new SimpleStringProperty(lName);
            this.age = new SimpleIntegerProperty(age);
        }

        public final StringProperty firstNameProperty() {
            return this.firstName;
        }

        public final java.lang.String getFirstName() {
            return this.firstNameProperty().get();
        }

        public final void setFirstName(final java.lang.String firstName) {
            this.firstNameProperty().set(firstName);
        }

        public final StringProperty lastNameProperty() {
            return this.lastName;
        }

        public final java.lang.String getLastName() {
            return this.lastNameProperty().get();
        }

        public final void setLastName(final java.lang.String lastName) {
            this.lastNameProperty().set(lastName);
        }

        public final IntegerProperty ageProperty() {
            return this.age;
        }

        public final int getAge() {
            return this.ageProperty().get();
        }

        public final void setAge(final int age) {
            this.ageProperty().set(age);
        }

    }


}
```

TableUtils.java

```
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

import javafx.beans.property.DoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TablePosition;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.input.Clipboard;
import javafx.scene.input.ClipboardContent;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCodeCombination;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCombination;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;

public class TableUtils {

    private static NumberFormat numberFormatter = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();


    /**
     * Install the keyboard handler:
     *   + CTRL + C = copy to clipboard
     *   + CTRL + V = paste to clipboard
     * @param table
     */
    public static void installCopyPasteHandler(TableView<?> table) {

        // install copy/paste keyboard handler
        table.setOnKeyPressed(new TableKeyEventHandler());

    }

    /**
     * Copy/Paste keyboard event handler.
     * The handler uses the keyEvent's source for the clipboard data. The source must be of type TableView.
     */
    public static class TableKeyEventHandler implements EventHandler<KeyEvent> {

        KeyCodeCombination copyKeyCodeCompination = new KeyCodeCombination(KeyCode.C, KeyCombination.CONTROL_ANY);
        KeyCodeCombination pasteKeyCodeCompination = new KeyCodeCombination(KeyCode.V, KeyCombination.CONTROL_ANY);

        public void handle(final KeyEvent keyEvent) {

            if (copyKeyCodeCompination.match(keyEvent)) {

                if( keyEvent.getSource() instanceof TableView) {

                    // copy to clipboard
                    copySelectionToClipboard( (TableView<?>) keyEvent.getSource());

                    // event is handled, consume it
                    keyEvent.consume();

                }

            } 
            else if (pasteKeyCodeCompination.match(keyEvent)) {

                if( keyEvent.getSource() instanceof TableView) {

                    // copy to clipboard
                    pasteFromClipboard( (TableView<?>) keyEvent.getSource());

                    // event is handled, consume it
                    keyEvent.consume();

                }

            } 

        }

    }

    /**
     * Get table selection and copy it to the clipboard.
     * @param table
     */
    public static void copySelectionToClipboard(TableView<?> table) {

        StringBuilder plainBuffer = new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder htmlBuffer = new StringBuilder();

        ObservableList<TablePosition> positionList = table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedCells();

        int prevRow = -1;

        htmlBuffer.append( "<html>\n<body>\n<table>\n");

        htmlBuffer.append( " <tr>\n");

        for (TablePosition position : positionList) {

            int viewRow = position.getRow();
            int viewCol = position.getColumn();

            // determine whether we advance in a row (tab) or a column
            // (newline).
            if (prevRow == viewRow) {

                plainBuffer.append('\t');

            } else if (prevRow != -1) {

                plainBuffer.append('\n');
                htmlBuffer.append( " </tr>\n <tr>\n");
            }

            // create string from cell
            String text = "";

            Object observableValue = (Object) table.getVisibleLeafColumn(viewCol).getCellObservableValue( viewRow); // table position gives the view index => we need to operate on the view columns

            // null-check: provide empty string for nulls
            if (observableValue == null) {
                text = "";
            }
            else if( observableValue instanceof DoubleProperty) { // TODO: handle boolean etc

                text = numberFormatter.format( ((DoubleProperty) observableValue).get());

            }
            else if( observableValue instanceof IntegerProperty) { 

                text = numberFormatter.format( ((IntegerProperty) observableValue).get());

            }                   
            else if( observableValue instanceof StringProperty) { 

                text = ((StringProperty) observableValue).get();

            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Unsupported observable value: " + observableValue);
            }

            // add new item to clipboard
            plainBuffer.append(text);
            htmlBuffer.append( "  <td>" + text + "</td>\n");

            // remember previous
            prevRow = viewRow;
        }

        htmlBuffer.append( " </tr>\n");
        htmlBuffer.append( "</table>\n</body>\n</html>");

        // create clipboard content
        final ClipboardContent clipboardContent = new ClipboardContent();
        clipboardContent.putString(plainBuffer.toString());
        clipboardContent.putHtml(htmlBuffer.toString());

        System.out.println("ascii:\n" + plainBuffer.toString() + "\n\nhtml:\n" + htmlBuffer.toString());

        // set clipboard content
        Clipboard.getSystemClipboard().setContent(clipboardContent);


    }

    public static void pasteFromClipboard( TableView<?> table) {

        // abort if there's not cell selected to start with
        if( table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedCells().size() == 0) {
            return;
        }

        // get the cell position to start with
        TablePosition pasteCellPosition = table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedCells().get(0);

        System.out.println("Pasting into cell " + pasteCellPosition);

        String pasteString = Clipboard.getSystemClipboard().getString();

        System.out.println(pasteString);

        int rowClipboard = -1;

        StringTokenizer rowTokenizer = new StringTokenizer( pasteString, "\n");
        while( rowTokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {

            rowClipboard++;

            String rowString = rowTokenizer.nextToken();

            StringTokenizer columnTokenizer = new StringTokenizer( rowString, "\t");

            int colClipboard = -1;

            while( columnTokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {

                colClipboard++;

                // get next cell data from clipboard
                String clipboardCellContent = columnTokenizer.nextToken();

                // calculate the position in the table cell
                int rowTable = pasteCellPosition.getRow() + rowClipboard;
                int colTable = pasteCellPosition.getColumn() + colClipboard;

                // skip if we reached the end of the table
                if( rowTable >= table.getItems().size()) {
                    continue;
                }
                if( colTable >= table.getColumns().size()) {
                    continue;
                }

                // System.out.println( rowClipboard + "/" + colClipboard + ": " + cell);

                // get cell
                TableColumn tableColumn = table.getVisibleLeafColumn(colTable);  // table position gives the view index => we need to operate on the view columns
                ObservableValue observableValue = tableColumn.getCellObservableValue(rowTable);

                System.out.println( rowTable + "/" + colTable + ": " +observableValue);

                // TODO: handle boolean, etc
                if( observableValue instanceof DoubleProperty) { 

                    try {

                        double value = numberFormatter.parse(clipboardCellContent).doubleValue();
                        ((DoubleProperty) observableValue).set(value);

                    } catch (ParseException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
                else if( observableValue instanceof IntegerProperty) { 

                    try {

                        int value = NumberFormat.getInstance().parse(clipboardCellContent).intValue();
                        ((IntegerProperty) observableValue).set(value);

                    } catch (ParseException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }                   
                else if( observableValue instanceof StringProperty) { 

                    ((StringProperty) observableValue).set(clipboardCellContent);

                } else {

                    System.out.println("Unsupported observable value: " + observableValue);

                }

                System.out.println(rowTable + "/" + colTable);
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: @Sredny M Casnanova: I updated the code to support html. So copying in the TableView and pasting into Word should result in Word having the same table structure.

Answer (score 0):

Get the text you want from the table data, formatted appropriately: then you can do

```
ClipboardContent content = new ClipboardContent();
content.putString(tableData);
Clipboard.getSystemClipboard().setContent(content);
```

Comment: all right, I get it. But one more thing, when you say "formatted appropriately" that means I'll only paste String in word? I want it looks like a table.

Comment: You said you wanted it in a text editor, so you can only possibly handle string data. You can obviously format it so columns are separated by tabs, etc.